# Add new file type to windows 7 preview pane

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

How can I add a new file type to my preview pane.

At this point I want to add the possibility to preview `.cbr` and `.cbz` files with my comic viewer.

But a general solution that would work with any file-type/application pair would be best.

**Note:**
I tried [Winhelponline’s PreviewConfig Utility](http://www.winvistaclub.com/t81.html) it does not allow me to match my file-types with a new application.

Answer (score 1):

I followed [this blog article](https://kickthatcomputer.wordpress.com/2013/02/08/enable-previews-for-new-file-extensions/) to add a text preview for a file type `.meta` I use and wanted to preview as text:

1. Associate a default program with the file type
2. Edit registry `HKCR\[.extension]`, e.g. `HKCR\.meta`, adding a new String value named `PerceivedType` and set it to `text`, or whatever PerceviedType you want.

That works fine if your [PerceivedType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144150(v=vs.85).aspx) already exists. The available values are the subkeys of `HKCR\SystemFileAssociations`. Hopefully you can use one of the existing ones ... otherwise try following instructions [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee872121(v=vs.85).aspx#reg_perceived_types) to add a new one:

**Registering a Perceived Type**

Registry values for perceived types are defined as subkeys of the
 `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations` registry subkey. 
 For example,
 the perceived type text is registered as follows:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT   
 SystemFileAssociations
       text
          shell
             edit
                command
                   (Default) = "%SystemRoot%\system32\NOTEPAD.EXE" "%1"
             open
                command
                   (Default) = "%SystemRoot%\system32\NOTEPAD.EXE" "%1"
```

NB: This is the same for Windows 7 and Windows 8